Как скачать docker image с официального сайта elastic.co?
Не получается
docker pull docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:8.15.0
с оф сайта https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docker.html
Рассказывают про блокировку:
The Amazon CloudFront distribution is configured to block access from your country.
Установил tor в ubuntu. Внешний ip меняет :
torsocks wget -qO - https://api.ipify.org;
Но при выполнении
$ torsocks docker pull docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:8.15.0
все равно блокируется подключение.
Что бы скрыть мой ip компа, установил прокси сервер в windows:
https://proxy-list.org/russian/index.php
Не помогло.
Установил vpn сервер в windows и скачал пакет
elasticsearch-8.14.3-amd64.deb
sudo dpkg -i elasticsearch-8.14.3-amd64.deb
завелся в ubuntu.
След шагом пытался запихнуть работающий elasticsearch в docker.
Но в Dockerfile
RUN dpkg -i elasticsearch-8.14.3-amd64.deb
ругается.
Если скачивать образ из docker хаба- там не будет секретного блока: user elastic, password, http_ca.crt.
Чего посоветуете?

Где не будет секретного блока? По идее образы не отличаются.

Образы не отличаются, но секретный блок устанавливается,показывается только с pulla с оф сайта. Ну у меня так(

действительно, образы разные. Про torsocks известно, что эта программа не работает с docker. Поэтому качать нужно c docker.elastio.co через VPN.

На ubuntu установлен openvpn сервер, клиент не подкл в windows -похоже провайдер блокирует. А через vpn серверы в windows на ubuntu ни как не скачать image с  docker.elastiс.co
